# Why doesn't GetSatelliteAssembly check version?

Tags: c#, globalization

I call `GetSatelliteAssembly(ci, version)` with the version of my exe and get a reference to the sattelite assembly.
But I know that the sattelite assembly has another version number. This I can confirm if I check the versions manually via `MyAssembly.GetName().Version`. The version of my exe is "0.0.34.0" and the version of the sattelite is "0.0.33.0". So, with my program GetSatelliteAssembly doesn't check the version.

Should GetSatelliteAssembly check the version?

Or when doesn't GetSatelliteAssembly check the version?

I'm using C# with .NET 4.5.

Comment: Are your assemblies strongly-named? Are sure you're not confusing file versions and assembly versions?

Comment: No not strong named. I'm retrieving the version via MyAssembly.GetName().Version.